# Redirecting localhost to domain in hosts file not working

Tags: apache, redirect, dns, localhost, fedora-25

I'm trying to redirect the domain `trottier.com` to my localhost on `Fedora 25`. I've done the required changes in the /etc/hosts file. Chrome redirects me to localhost just fine, my website is up and running there (with XAMPP). However, whenever I try to access `trottier.com`, Chrome opens an actual website from the web.

When I log onto the root user through Fedora's login screen, however, I am able to perfectly access my website through `trottier.com`. From my regular user (which has root privilege), I can `ping trottier.com` and it returns this:

```
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
```

Any idea on how I could access the domain without having to change my user session to root ?

Thank you.

Comment: "*I've done the required changes in the /etc/hosts file.*" ... what changes did you do in `/etc/hosts`? Chrome is using some cache for the DNS responses. Give it a try tomorrow or try to flush the cache.

Comment: This is the current content of my hosts file:

![host](https://i.imgur.com/HXlCk2V.png)

Comment: I tried accessing the website today, still nothing.